# How do I prevent the android keyboard push my container up?

Tags: android, html, css, responsive-design, keyboard

So I'm doing a website with a ["Modal Popup"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gLWIYk0Sd38&) login form responsive to mobile first and I have a footer to the end of the modal container. The problem is when I want to write something in both inputs, the keyboard appears and it push the footer up. I want the footer to stay in the position and the keyboard just don't resize my modal container or have interaction with the website.

[This is how it look without showing the keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DhOZW.jpg)

[And this is when it push the footer up.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tNBg.jpg)

Here's the code.

```css
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

header{
    background-color:red;
    width:100%;
    height:30px;
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.to-modal-container{
    background-color:blue;
    width:100%;
    height:200px;
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.to-modal{
    background:red;
}

.bg-modal{
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    position:absolute;
    top: 0;
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.modal-content{
    width:90%;
    height:50%;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 4px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 20px;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content:space-between;
}

input {
    width:50%;
    display: block;
    margin:15px auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>MODAL TESTING</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style.css">
</head>
<body>
<header>
    <div>
        <span>LOGO</span>
    </div>
</header>
<div class="to-modal-container">
    <div class="to-modal">
        <span><a href="#">CLICK AQUI</a></span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="bg-modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <span>LOGO</span>
        <div class="form-container">
        <form action="">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Name">
            <input type="Password" placeholder="Password">
            <a href="" class="button">Submit</a>
        </form>
        </div>
        <div class="footer-container">
            <span>THIS IS THE FOOTER</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I played around with the code you have shared and noticed that you have set the Height of `modal-content` to 90%.

So it re-adjusts the height of your Modal to 90% of the screen height available which changes when the keyboard is open.

So my recommendation is to set a fixed height like `300px` instead of % and have a different height for mobile devices using media-queries.

```
.modal-content{
    width:90%;
    /* height:50%; */
    height: 300px;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 4px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 20px;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content:space-between;
}
```

Let me know if you need any more clarification.

Comment: It was so simple! Thank you a lot. I was so frustrating that I become blind and didn't see that.